# Qt: pointer auto deletion after program exit

Tags: c++, qt

Do I have to delete pointer if program will exit soon?

Like this:

```
#include "mainwidget.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWidget w;
    w.show();

    int *a = new int[5];

    delete []a;
    return a.exec();
}
```

Do I really have to call `delete []a;` or It doesn't matter because `after return a.exec();` (`main()` funtcion finishes) all pointers will be destroyed automatically?

Comment: Does this really let you declare `a` twice in the same scope?

Comment: Why did you not select the answer? Anything missing?

Answer (score 0):

All reusable resources are reclaimed by the operating system when your program exits (with a few special exceptions, like perhaps sockets and sometimes shared memory). But in this case, it will be reclaimed.

If you want to get into good habits though, use `std::unique_ptr<int[]>` (or if the size is really a constant and is that small, just `int a[5]` or `std::array<int, 5>`) to store the pointer, then you don't have to worry about `delete[]` at all.